# What is distribution of $ \frac{\sqrt{n}\bar{X}_n}{\sqrt{1-\bar{X}_n^2}} $?

Tags: probability, statistics

For iid samples $X_1,\dots, X_n$, define $\bar{X}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. From CLT, we have
$$
\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)\to N(0,\sigma^2)
$$
in distribution. This means $\bar{X}_n\to N(\mu, \sigma^2/n).$

Also, we know $\bar{X}_n\to \mu$ in probability from WLLN.

I am confused if I used Slutsky's theorem that
$$
\frac{\bar{X}_n}{\sqrt{1-\bar{X}_n^2}}\to \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\mu^2}}N(\mu, \sigma^2/n)
$$
Is this one, right? Otherwise, what is the distribution of
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)}{\sqrt{1-\bar{X}_n^2}}
$$

Comment: Note $\bar X_n\to N(μ,\sigma^2/n)$ is not precise since it is an asymptotic result ($n\to \infty$); the first way you write it is better (assuming you mean convergence in distr.)

Comment: Also, for your final question, use Slutsky's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, without knowing the distributions of the original $X_i$'s, it is impossible to compute $\frac{\sqrt{n}\bar{X}_n}{\sqrt{1-\bar{X}_n^2}}$.

Secondly, there are two different arrow notations, and you have to be careful which one to use.

The first one is the "regular limit", seen in $\bar{X}_n \rightarrow \mu$. This means that

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \quad \lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(|\bar{X}_n - \mu| > \varepsilon) = 0,$$

or the chance that the $\bar{X}_n$ observations will significantly differ from $\mu$ goes to $0$ over time.

The other limit is "limit in distribution", or what the distribution function of $\bar{X}_n$ will approach over time, often denoted as "$\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}$".

$\bar{X}_n \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$ means that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\bar{X}_n \le x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \cdot \sqrt{2\pi n}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2/n}}.$$

The formula you've obtained mixed both of these notations, I'm not even sure which "limit" notation it uses, because it contains both a $\mu$ and a distribution:

$$\frac{\bar{X}_n}{\sqrt{1-\bar{X}_n^2}}\to \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\mu^2}}N(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$$

The lower $\bar{X}_n^2$ turned into a $\mu$, while the upper $\bar{X}_n$ turned into the aforementioned distribution. While it's going to be much more difficult to calculate the actual distribution of the given formula, and it might depend on the original distribution of the $X_i's$, the "limit" in the first sense is easy once we know that $\bar{X}_n \to \mu$:

$$\frac{\bar{X}_n}{\sqrt{1-\bar{X}_n^2}}\to \frac{\mu}{\sqrt{1-\mu^2}}$$